# vtiger crm delete default fields (e.g. Accounts >> Created Time)

Tags: php, html, crm, vtiger

Is it possible to delete, change or rename default fields in vtiger crm. An example would be: Accounts >> Account Name or Persons >> Created Time.

How is it possible to allocate users on fields. I want to copy this configuration to another field. e.g.: Persons >> Handler.

On the Products >> List View Page I want to delete the field Commission Rate (%), Qty. in Stock and Qty/Unit. Is it possible to replace these fields (Commission Rate > Serial No)...

The field: Account No. Can this field be defined manually. Due to the fact, that I have my own Account No. I want to define my own ones. ACC1 > e.g. SCP

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I suggest to read carefully the user manual: http://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Vtiger521:User_Manual

and the developers' howtos at this link: http://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Developers_How_To%27s

On the second link, you will find this answer to your question regarding how to rename default fields: http://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Developers_How_To%27s#How_to_change_default_field_names

In the manual, you will find how to hide fields (you need to hide the Commission Rate field): http://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/vtiger510:UserManual_Administration_Tools_Module_Settings#Fields

On the same link you will learn how to create custom fields (i.e. in order to store your own Acct No).

Finally, if you need to update automatically some fields, you have to look for Workflows, or Events. If you need to add new modules, search for Vtlib API

Comment: Unfortunately, the links containing Vtiger521 & Vtiger510 are dead links. I tried to load them in archive.org but Vtiger has the pages blocked from crawling. Any chance you have a link to the latest version of the info?

Comment: I have figured out how to do most of the modding I needed in the Database so I don't need these links...but others might. Unfortunately, the database method I took is very usage specific so it is hard to explain that route. (uitypes, tabids, blockids, etc all have to be modified in the database style)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit field names in two ways:

1. go to vtiger_fields and edit you fieldlabel
2. go to language pack of the module and edit that

Answer (score 0):

I tried the links above and they are not valid anymore.

In case someone is looking for the way to hide it:
I managed to hide these fields by changing displaytype column in vtiger_field table of the field we want to hide to 0